# Array error of image insertion in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently using this codes and this code works to my other file but i tried to used this code again and there's an error occurred. As i check it all of my declarations are correct in my visions and understandings help if there's some lines or declaration i haven't see yet that causes of error

My: HotelViewDetails.php

```html
<form action="FeedbackUpload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="review_title" placeholder="Title" />
    <textarea name="limitedtextarea" required></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" id="SubmitReview" name="submitfeedback"value="Submit">
    </form>
```

My: FeedbackUpload.php

```html
 <?php
 session_start();
 $user_id = $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];
 
    $role = $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
    
    $Address = $_SESSION['sess_address'];
    
    $City = $_SESSION['sess_city'];
    
    $avatar = $_SESSION['avatar'];
 
 $currentuser = $_SESSION['sess_username'];
 
 $first_name = $_SESSION['sess_first_name'];
 
 $last_name = $_SESSION['sess_last_name'];
 
 $id = $_SESSION['sess_hotel_id'];
 
 
 $_SESSION['hotel_name'] = $name;
 
 $_SESSION['hotel_image'] = $image;
 
    if(isset($_POST["submitfeedback"]))
    {
    $link=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "lakbayph", "aaEPl6122n");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"lakbayph_category");
    $title_of_feedback = $_POST['review_title'];
    $textarea = $_POST['limitedtextarea'];
    $count=0;
    $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from Reviews where review_title='$title_of_feedback'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($res);
      if($count>0)
      {
       echo "Sorry, this title is already used, try again";
       
      }
      else
      {
        print_r($_FILES);
        $avatar_path = $link->real_escape_string('images/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name']);
        if(preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['avatar']['type'])) {
         
          if(copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $avatar_path)){
              
           mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `Reviews` VALUES('','$id','NONE','NONE','NONE','$user_id','$title_of_feedback','$textarea','$avatar_path')");
           echo 'Registration succesful! Added $username to the database!';
           header("location: SearcResult.php");
           
           
           if ($link->query($sql) === true) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration succesful! Added $username to the database!';
            header("location: welcome.php");
           }
           else {
            echo "User could not be added to the database!";
           }
          }
          else{
           echo "File upload failed!";
          }
        }
        else{
          echo "Please only upload GIF and JPEG";
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
```

This is my error

[image: Error occured]

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is missing.

Comment: Oh it works. Haha thanks sir. Sorry i forgot to place this code.